# django how to redirect url after create post on the same edit post

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

This is my url where I want to redirect after post.i want render in add_choise

```
path('edit/<int:blerje_id>/produkti/add/', views.add_choice, name="add_choice"),
```

This is my view.

```
 def add_poll(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
    form = PollForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_blerje = form.save(commit=False)
        new_blerje.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        new_blerje.owner = request.user
        new_blerje.save() 
        messages.success(
                        request,
                        'Fatura u krijua me sukses, kliko butonin me poshte per te shtuar produktet!',
                        extra_tags='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show'
                        )
        return redirect('polls:edit',)
else:
    form = PollForm()
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'polls/add_poll.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the view is `add_choice`, so you can redirect with:

```
return redirect('polls:add_choice', blerje_id=new_blerje.pk)
```

Here we thus use the primary key `.pk` to fill in as value for `blerje_id`.

Comment: Reverse for 'add_choice' not found. 'add_choice' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: @mario: did you define, by any chance an `app_name`?

Comment: Yes, app_name="polls"

Comment: @mario: then it is `polls:add_choice`.